# Python , Pseudocode conversion with lists and for statements

Tags: python, list, for-loop, pseudocode

I'm having trouble with this for statement The pseudocode is `index = 0` to size-1 I've tried a lot of different python statements searched the internet but it still comes up syntax error.

```
len = 10

index = 0
movielist = len

for index , (len-1):
    movielist[index] = raw_input("please enter the names of your 10 favorite Netflix movies  ") 
    index = index + 1

while index < len:
    print "Your favorite Netflix movies are  " + movielist[index]
```

Comment: What is `for index , (len-1):` meant to do?

Comment: Cannot belive that you have checked the python documentation, sorry :). Your for loop is syntactically incorrect. `for index in range(0, len-1):` might work

Comment: `movielist = len` makes it a variable not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop isn't correctly expressed. RTFM https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
length = 10
movielist = []

print("please enter the names of your 10 favorite Netflix movies")

for i in range(length):
    movielist.append(raw_input("what is movie %d? " % (i + 1)))

print("Your favorite Netflix movies are")

for movie in movielist:
    print(movie)
```

You can use the function `range` to loop a certain number of times and then append what is input to a `list`. Then you can display those list entries by iterating over the list and printing each one. It is generally considered bad practice to actually maintain a loop variable in python, like you might in c etc. You almost never need one.

I suggest you find a good python tutorial and go through it.

Comment: I'm taking a programming logic and design course which involves just pseudocode and flowcharts I have no knowledge of Python but the teacher has us use python to convert the pseudocode into code to show the logic She shows some examples in her notes but that isn't much so I'm learning python with  online tutorials but I just started Thanks for your help and quick response Paul Rooney and Pasqual Guerrero now to explain how I came up with this program no problem they don't teach it but they want you to know it  I be on here again thanks again